# After using custom login form , OAuth2 server not redirecting to client server

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, oauth-2.0

> Authentication and Authorization is working fine. But after successful login it not redirecting me to client side further it open source code of some .js file. While previous (without custom login form loginPage("/login")) it successfully redirecting me to last page clicked (client side) which called for authenticate.
>
> My Server side code as below:

**Authorization server**

```
@Configuration

@EnableAuthorizationServer

public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {

    security.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()")
            .checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
}


@Override
public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
    clients
            .inMemory()
            .withClient("ClientId")
            .secret("secret")
            .authorizedGrantTypes("authorization_code")
            .scopes("user_info")
            .redirectUris("http://localhost:8082/ui/login")
            .autoApprove(true);
}


@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {

    endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
}
}
```

**Resource Server**

```
@Configuration

@EnableResourceServer

public class ResourceServer extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {
@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.requestMatchers().antMatchers("/api/**").and().authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated().and()
            .antMatcher("/rest/hello/principal")
            .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
}
```

**My Security Config**

```
@Configuration

public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


@Autowired
private CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login").permitAll().antMatchers("/oauth/token/revokeById/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/tokens/**").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated().and()
        .formLogin().loginPage("/login")
        .usernameParameter("username")
        .passwordParameter("password")
        .failureUrl("/login?error")
        .defaultSuccessUrl("/").permitAll().and()
        .csrf().disable();
        
}

@Override
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordencoder());
}

@Bean(name = "passwordEncoder")
public PasswordEncoder passwordencoder() {
    return new CustomPasswordEncoder();
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to create
SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler implementation

```
public class RefererRedirectionAuthenticationSuccessHandler 
  extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler
  implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {
 
    public RefererRedirectionAuthenticationSuccessHandler() {
        super();
        setUseReferer(true);
    }
 
}
```

and add one line to the WebSecurityConfiguration
.successHandler(new RefererRedirectionAuthenticationSuccessHandler())

And after that you method will look like as shown below

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login").permitAll().antMatchers("/oauth/token/revokeById/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/tokens/**").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated().and()
        .formLogin().loginPage("/login")
        .usernameParameter("username")
        .passwordParameter("password")
        .successHandler(new RefererRedirectionAuthenticationSuccessHandler()) 
        .failureUrl("/login?error")
        .defaultSuccessUrl("/").permitAll().and()
        .csrf().disable();

}
```

Comment: thanks for above but the result is same , i tried with debug point on RefererRedirectionAuthenticationSuccessHandler() but it seem, that the control not going over it.

Comment: It does not work if we have a different name for the login page like `custom-login.jsp`. But if it is `login.jsp`, this working properly. Thanks @AlexanderPetrov